# What's the meaning of "be good of sb"?

Tags: prepositions

> “I should like very much to see her,” thought the soldier; but he could not obtain permission to do so. However, he passed a very pleasant time; went to the theatre, drove in the king’s garden, and gave a great deal of money to the poor, which was very good ***of him***;

This is a part of the fairy tale "The Tinder-Box" by Hans Christian Andersen.

"which was very good ***of him***", I don't have the faintest idea what it means.

What's the meaning of "be good ***of sb***"?

And what's the difference with "be good ***for sb***"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the sentence ***good of you***, the preposition ***[of](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/of)*** has the following meaning:

> used after an adjective when judging someone's behaviour:
>
> - It was mean of you to mention her weight.
> - Thank you so much for my present. How thoughtful of you.

(Cambridge Dictionary)

***[Good for](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/good%20for%20(someone%20or%20something))*** someone:

> resulting in something good or desirable for (someone or something)
>
> - Regular exercise is good for you.
> - Hot soup is good for a cold.
> - Being with friends is especially good for him right now.

(M-W)